# Force close when hitting send

Tags: android, string, methods

I keep getting a force close on my app that I am learning from the android developers site. I type it and then when I hit the send it force closes. here is some of my code in question. This is the activity from when the app first shows up to when I would hit the send button:

```
package gov.gforce.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyFirstAppActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "gov.gforce.myapp.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        /** Called when the user selects the Send button*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
```

here is the activity from the display after the button is pressed:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyFirstAppActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);{

        }

       // Create the text view
       TextView textView = new TextView(this);
       textView.setTextSize(40);
       textView.setText(message);

       setContentView(textView);
```

and here is my app manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="gov.gforce.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="gov.gforce.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what does the DDMS say?  so you can figure out what's wrong with your codes. and where is you send button?

Comment: Post the stacktrace from DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, your manifest is formatted wrong for the `<activity>` elements...

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="gov.gforce.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You've embedded your `DisplayMessageActivity` inside your `MyFirstAppActivity` block. Change it to this...

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="gov.gforce.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity"/>
```

I'm also slightly worried about the way you pasted some of the other code but as long as it's just typos in there, it might not be relevant.

Comment: thanks for the fix. I was following the training session verbatim on the android developers site. i'm not sure how it lead me to this.

Answer (score 0):

You've managed to somehow nest your activities ... these should actually be declared side by side within your application tag in the xml manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity">
       <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="gov.gforce.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity"/>

</application>
```

You need to learn how to read the logcat messages.  For more information go to developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

your AndroidManifest declaration is wrong  tag shouldn't be neasted, Change your AndroidManifest like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gov.gforce.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick. So by nesting basically meaning that I had an activity within a activity? is there ever a good time to have nested activity or that concept can never work? and I copied this information straight from the android developers training session.